# Using 3rd party API in a ASP.NET MVC 3 website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

In our website we are pulling content from [Zendesk](http://www.zendesk.com), [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com), [StopForumSpam](http://www.stopforumspam.com) via API. How can we prevent our website from blocking when these servers are down?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best solution found so far:

```
public static bool IsReady(string uri)
{
   // Create a new 'HttpWebRequest' Object to the mentioned URL.
   HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);

   // Set the 'Timeout' property of the HttpWebRequest to 1000 milliseconds.
   myHttpWebRequest.Timeout = 1000;

   HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse;

   try
   {
      // A HttpWebResponse object is created and is GetResponse Property of the HttpWebRequest associated with it 
      myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
      return false;
   }

   return myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;

}
```

Comment: From some days with this URI, it doesn't work anymore: `http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService`. Can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

Implement a reasonable timeout policy in your API calls. You need to make sure you strike the balance between something just taking longer to load than usual and something being unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MVC4/.NET 4.5+, you can use [async and await](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4) to call the remote services, which will allow your application to process other operations while waiting for the network I/O to complete.

Edit: You'll still have to provide logic to manage errors/timeouts, but you won't be locking as many resources while waiting for a timeout to be triggered.

If you search around there's plenty of tutorials covering the use of async/await for network IO tasks.

Edit2: Valverij pointed out that (from the title of the question) you're obviously not able to use MVC4/.NET 4.5+, so you're going to need to use the much more verbose [Asynchronous Controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) approach to achieve the same effect.

Comment: All the links you provided explain how to run an asynchronous method, what about a sample on quitting after 1000 ms?